# Implement IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET webforms 4.7.2

Tags: asp.net, webforms, frameworks, httpclient, ihttpclientfactory

I'm trying to implement IHttpClientFactory in my project created with webforms, .NET Framework 4.7.2 :

- Global.asax :

  ```
    public static IServiceProvider ServiceProvider;

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var container = this.AddUnity();
        container.RegisterType<IHttpClientFactoryProvider, HttpClientFactoryProvider>();
        container.RegisterType<IMyanager, MyManager>();

        var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder();
        hostBuilder.ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices);
        var host = hostBuilder.Build();

        ServiceProvider = host.Services;

        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient();
    }
  ```
- The class that call IHttpClientFactory:

  ```
    public class HttpClientFactoryProvider : IHttpClientFactoryProvider
    {
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public HttpClientFactoryProvider(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public string GetData()
    {
        var test = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

        return "";
    }
    }
  ```
- MyManager that inject HttpClientFactoryProvider :

  ```
    public class MyManager : IMyanager
     {
      private readonly IHttpClientFactoryProvider _httpClientFactoryProvider;

      public MyManager(IHttpClientFactoryProvider httpClientFactoryProvider)
     {
        _httpClientFactoryProvider = httpClientFactoryProvider;
     }

     public string GetData()
     {
        return _httpClientFactoryProvider.GetData();
     }
   }
  ```
- Page Default.aspx:

  ```
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
     private readonly IMyanager _mymanager;

     public _Default(IMyanager mymanager)
     {
        _mymanager = mymanager;
     }

     public _Default()
     {

     }

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var result = _mymanager.GetData();
        }
    }
  }
  ```

The problem is that _mymanager is always null, i have done all possible solutions but nothing.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution?